# Identify this bag: yellows, oranges and browns

Tags: set-identification

I have this bag and zero idea what it’s from? Any well eyed individuals who can spot the set? [image]

Answer (score 3):

Based on two 1x4x2 arches in Medium Nougat colour, and four rubber tyres, this is [set 10704 Creative Box](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=10704-1).